# Making an image stay at the bottom of the page but not go over content

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I have an a logo image that is supposed to remain at the bottom of a nav drawer. The only way I know to have it be at the bottom is with the absolute and bottom properties, but that's causing it to overlap the list items on a short device (shrink the height of the browser window until scroll bar appears). As soon as the scroll bars appear, the logo will go over top of the list items.

Here's my sandbox with a drawer and random fake image: https://codesandbox.io/s/drawer-with-image-at-bottom-xpuhp

Is there a way to start it at the bottom without using absolute? And/or a way keep it at the bottom until the window height necessitates scroll bars and then have it be part of that scrollable content behavior? If that makes sense. I've played around with variations of flex properties, but I don't really understand it. If I remove absolute it starts way up under the last list item in drawer and I need it at the bottom until scrollbar.

my css for the img:

```
logo: {
      width: "220px",
      height: "150px",
      marginLeft: "50px",
      marginRight: "50px",
      bottom: "24px",
      position: "absolute"
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would use is a wrapper (in this example with the class `container`) that has a display of `flex`. The children (a list and your image) should be on the **vertical axis**, therefore use `flex-direction: column;` so your main axis is vertical. And because you want your first child (your list) at the beginning and your last child at the end (your image) you can use `justify-content: space-between;`. This will distribute your items evenly, with your first item at the start and last item at the end. Flex may be hard to understand at first, but it is very powerful. Some information that might help:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox
and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Here's an example of what I wrote about (open in a full page and resize to see the effect):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  /* You can leave this out or change it to 100% depending on your situation*/
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
  </ul>
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/300/200" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, let me give this a few tweaks and see what I can learn.

Comment: That works exactly like I wanted! I made a stupid mistake on my first try using camelCase for the value of space-between in the style obj.  Interestingly, though, when I take away the column direction it still works. Anyway, thanks v much.

Comment: The reason why it might work without the column direction is when your content is being wrapped, meaning when it does not 'fit' on one row, it will wrap below. If the width of the container would be greater, you will see it will remain on a single row and you won't get the desired effect. Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing position to relative and bottom to -24px:

```
logo: {
      width: "220px",
      height: "150px",
      marginLeft: "50px",
      marginRight: "50px",
      bottom: "-24px",
      position: "realtive"
    }
```

Check out the [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/drawer-with-image-at-bottom-forked-py0v7) with these changes. With this you can then tweak the bottom property to whatever you see fit, placing it how far to the bottom you like.

Comment: thank you but that link just points to what looks like an exact copy of my sandbox. it has absolute and 24px.

Comment: Shoot, I'm terribly sorry. I forgot to save my changes before I linked it. Try it now, please! I any case, you can try it yourself, too!

Comment: so on the sandbox I had to set it to something like -550px with relative. That's a bit confusing to me though because with bottom: 24px, I know that it's always going to be just a tiny bit above the bottom so it doesn't run up to the bottom edge, regardless of what screen is viewing it. But with -550px, won't that change the space from the bottom by a wide margin depending on the height of the user's screen? what if they have 4K screen (2180). Maybe I'm just not clear on how it works.

Comment: Ok, yeah, the image is still appearing right underneath the last list item. Not at the bottom. So with relative, it's just saying "go 24px under the last list item", right?